# javascript object literal pattern constructor error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to organize my code using the object literal pattern, but I am getting an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: backToTop is not defined

Any ideas why?

Here's the code:

```
(function($){

  var Mk = {

    config: {},

    init: function(config) {
      backToTop();
      wow();
      progressBarAnimation();
      slabText();
    },

    backToTop: function() {
      $('body').append('<div id="toTop" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> Back to Top</div>');
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
          $('#toTop').fadeIn();
        } else {
          $('#toTop').fadeOut();
        }
      }); 
      $('#toTop').click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
        return false;
      });
    },

    wow: function() {
      var wow = new WOW({
        boxClass:     'wow',      
        animateClass: 'animated', 
        offset:       0,          
        mobile:       true,       
        live:         true        
      });
      wow.init(); 
    },

    progressBarAnimation: function() {
      $.each($('div.progress-bar'),function(){
        $(this).css('width', $(this).attr('aria-valuetransitiongoal')+'%');
      });
    },

    slabText:function() {
      $("h1.mklife").slabText({
        "viewportBreakpoint":400
      });
    },

    last:''

  };

  $(document).ready(Mk.init());
  window.Mk = Mk;

})(jQuery)
```

- Edit: I had missed the actual function call parentheses on document ready: $(document).ready(Mk.init());

Comment: you are referencing a function in same object, so use this.backToTop(); instead

Answer (score 3):

The functions `backToTop`,`wow`,`progressBarAnimation`,`slabText` are methods of the Mk object, to access them reference the Mk object

```
init: function(config) {
  Mk.backToTop();
  Mk.wow();
  Mk.progressBarAnimation();
  Mk.slabText();
},
```

or since init is also a method of the same object you can access the function with the `this` keyword

```
init: function(config) {
  this.backToTop();
  this.wow();
  this.progressBarAnimation();
  this.slabText();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

backToTop is not a global variable so you need to call it using the object notation (this.backToTop)

The above solution would work but I recommend a cleaner approach using the revealing module design pattern, check this link (and the resources at the bottom of the page) on how to implement it https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/